# Java Compiler String optimization

Tags: java, string, compiler-construction

It seems reasonable to me that the compiler is going to take something like this:

```
log.info("A really long logger message that is kind of a pain in the tucous " + 
    "and violates formatting standards by making the line to long");
```

and compile the two Strings into one.  I'm pretty sure this is true but I would like
to have my ducks in a row if anyone brings it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if what JLS says about constant expressions is true I complied this code, Test.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.warning("123" + "456");
}
```

then decompile Test.class with Jad and got this

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    log.warning("123456");
}
```

that is, in Test.class there is only one literal "123456"

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this will be handled by the [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) part of the Java Language Specification.  In particular see part [15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Answer (score 8):

> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>   compile time and then treated as if they were literals.

Show that quote from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5) to anyone who 'challenges' you.